# Setting up an incremental development enviroment for c++ game engine

Tags: c++, editor, game-engine

Suppose I have written a game engine in c++. It was functions such as adPlayer(Vec3f position, Model playerModel), addExplosion(Vec3f position, Size explosionSize).

Now, those functions can be called in some sort of test class and then the projcet can be compiled and run. This takes forever.

What would be ideal is to have some basic text editor where i can type these functions, press ctrl+u and then this somehows calls the precompiled functions of the game engine. E.g, it doesn't recompile the game engine.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would compile your engine into a .dll and link it to your project. Then you can just link the function and don't have to compile it if you just want to use the functions.

Comment: Sounds good. But each time I want to change something I must re-run the application? How would I go about so that the game window is always open and when I for example swap player model it just switches on-the-fly?

Comment: Afaik there is no tool with which you can use a hot code change in C++ (there is in Java with eclipse and C# with VS). 
But what you can do is to integrate a scripting language like lua or python and than reload the scripts after you changed them. Implicitly this is kind of a recompilation of the script code but a lot faster than recompiling the project. But you have to write some logic as a script but that is not so unusual for games.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are asking about design iteration**, you create a data format that is read in and converted to entities in your scene graph. You need to use the factory pattern. You can use a serialization library where each object knows how to read/write/persist itself.

By having a data format that represents a "snapshot" of your game state, you can read/save it from both a game and an editor. Later you can make design changes to a running game instance by having functions that re-read the data during runtime

It seems like right now you might have hardcoded/mixed client code with engine code, which might be hard to seperate.

**If you are asking about compilation**, then you will want to compile to a library (either .dll or static .lib/.so). Then compile your client/specific code against your engine lib(s). They should be in seperate projects.

Comment: I think I was asking about the latter :)